# Why can't I import AndroidJUnit4 and ActivityTestRule into my unit test class?

Tags: android, android-support-library, junit4, android-espresso

I'm having trouble importing some of the Android UI testing framework classes - I just can't figure out what is going wrong!

This is my class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class ExampleUnitTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class);

@Test
public void listGoesOverTheFold() {
    onView(withText("Hello world!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
  }
}
```

But for some reason I get the errors 'cannot find symbol ActivityTestRule' and 'cannot find symbol AndroidJUnit4'. I've tried to import them but they cannot be found.

The dependencies in build.gradle are set to:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

So I think I have all the dependencies setup - I've been trying many things but with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What directory is your test class in - `test/java` or `androidTest/java`?

Comment: It's under test/java

Comment: What if my test is in `androidTest/java`, and I'm having this problem?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are two different types of tests you can set up in Android

**Unit Tests**

- These run directly on the JVM and do not have access to the Android framework classes.
- They are kept in the `test/java` package
- Dependencies need to added in the build.gradle file with the command `testCompile`
- You generally use Mockito, Robolectric & JUnit for these tests

**Instrumentation Tests**

- These run on an Android emulator and have full access to all the Android classes
- They are kept in the `androidTest/java` package
- Dependencies need to be added to build.gradle with `androidTestCompile`
- You generally use Espresso and JUnit for these tests

From what I can tell you are trying to write instrumentation tests with Espresso but have your test in the `test/java` package which is for unit tests.  In that case you need to move your test class to the `androidTest/java` package.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it! I didn't realise there was a difference between test/java and androidTest/java

Comment: Make sure you also TestImplement `'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 141):

Add these in the newer version:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 67):

If you migrated to AndroidX, use this:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 37):

Adding:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
```

solves problem, but don't forget to sync the project with gradle files. Only then the changes will take effect.

Comment: note: com.android.support packages are deprecated now. Developers should use androidx equivalent packages

Answer (score 24):

need this add dependencies

```
 testCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
 testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Comment: 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5' and 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5' are for androidTest, not test. so it should be
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

Comment: androidTestImplementation form Android Studio 3.x on

Answer (score 14):

From androidX use

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
```

In your dependencies section in your app level build.gradle file

for eg :

```
 dependencies {

     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
 }
```

Then import

import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

Answer (score 11):

Add dependency.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Answer (score 8):

For writing **UI tests**((tests that run on Android Device/Emulator)) in Android, make sure that

1. The Test classes are in ***androidTest*** package rather that ***test*** package.
2. Make sure you make the following dependencies in build.gradle

> ```
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
> testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
> ```

For **Unit Testing**(tests that run on JVM) make sure

1.Test classes are in ***test*** package

2.Make sure you make the following dependencies in build.gradle

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'
```

Comment: Adding the androidTestImplementation  and testImplementation did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using ActivityScenarioRule worked for me.

```
    @Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add these dependencies

```
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

Comment: The similar answer is already exists: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443155/596566